# SQL agregate values in one table and combine with counts from another table

Tags: sql, count

I want to take grouped values (column: 'Criticality') from one table dbo.VTM_duedate and next count values (column: 'DEVICE_NAME') in another table dbo.TPM_scan based on grouped values.

Table 1

```
USE tempdb;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.VTM_duedate') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.VTM_duedate;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.VTM_duedate
(
Criticality   varchar(30) NOT NULL,
KB        varchar(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.VTM_duedate(Criticality, KB)
VALUES('Medium', 157848);
INSERT INTO dbo.VTM_duedate(Criticality, KB)
VALUES('High', 155439);
INSERT INTO dbo.VTM_duedate(Criticality, KB)
VALUES('High', 635533);
INSERT INTO dbo.VTM_duedate(Criticality, KB)
VALUES('Critical', 189164);
INSERT INTO dbo.VTM_duedate(Criticality, KB)
VALUES('High', 188641);
INSERT INTO dbo.VTM_duedate(Criticality, KB)
VALUES('Critical', 537990);
INSERT INTO dbo.VTM_duedate(Criticality, KB)
VALUES('Critical', 1349605);
INSERT INTO dbo.VTM_duedate(Criticality, KB)
VALUES('Critical', 5646789);
INSERT INTO dbo.VTM_duedate(Criticality, KB)
VALUES('Medium', 6545789);
INSERT INTO dbo.VTM_duedate(Criticality, KB)
VALUES('High', 5637965);
INSERT INTO dbo.VTM_duedate(Criticality, KB)
VALUES('Medium', 6464367) ;
INSERT INTO dbo.VTM_duedate(Criticality, KB)
VALUES('Medium', 1323123) ;
INSERT INTO dbo.VTM_duedate(Criticality, KB)
VALUES('Medium', 1004326) ;
GO
```

Table 2

```
USE tempdb;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.TPM_scan') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.TPM_scan;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TPM_scan
(
DEVICE_NAME   varchar(30) NOT NULL,
APP_ID        varchar(10) NOT NULL,
Criticality   varchar(10) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_scan(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID, Criticality)
VALUES('LDNSQLF700', 157848, 'Medium');
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_scan(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID, Criticality)
VALUES('LDNSQLF700', 155439, 'High');
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_scan(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID, Criticality)
VALUES('LDNSQLF700', 635533, 'High');
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_scan(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID, Criticality)
VALUES('NYSQL502', 189164, 'Critical');
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_scan(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID, Criticality)
VALUES('NYSQL502', 188641, 'High');
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_scan(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID, Criticality)
VALUES('AUSSQL140', 537990, 'High');
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_scan(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID, Criticality)
VALUES('AUSSQL140', 1349605, 'Critical');
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_scan(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID, Criticality)
VALUES('JAP543X2', 5646789, 'Medium');
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_scan(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID, Criticality)
VALUES('EU456CLX', 6545789, 'Critical');
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_scan(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID, Criticality)
VALUES('EUCTX654', 5637965, 'High');
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_scan(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID, Criticality)
VALUES('EUCTX654', 6464367, 'Medium') ;
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_scan(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID, Criticality)
VALUES('EUCTX654', 1323123, 'High') ;
INSERT INTO dbo.TPM_scan(DEVICE_NAME, APP_ID, Criticality)
VALUES('EUCTX654', 1004326, 'Medium') ;
GO
```

Expected results:

```
Criticality   Device_count
 Critical           3
 High               6
 Medium             4
```

Comment: Providing sample data like this makes answering the question so much easier on us. Thanks for being thorough and complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just select the distinct list of Criticalitys from dbo.VTM_duedate in a derived table and join that to dbo.TPM_scan and get your counts!

```
select
    s.Criticality,
    count(*) as 'Device_Count'
from
    (select distinct Criticality from dbo.VTM_duedate) d
    inner join dbo.TPM_scan s
        on  d.Criticality = s.Criticality
group by
    s.Criticality
```

Comment: Great. That's all I needed. Thank you @Derek.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to get your answer when I built your schema in SQLFiddle.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Device_Count, Criticality
FROM TPM_scan
GROUP BY criticality
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c5287/6

Comment: Yea, this one works as well. I just need to get base criteria from the first table as some of them might be missing in the second one. Thank You @Aushin.